# Can I remove /etc/interfaces.d/setup after switching from ifupdown to network-manager?

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface, ifconfig, ifupdown

After having used `network-manager` on Debian stable (previously, 11, and now, 12) for quite a while, I decided to finally get rid of `ifupdown` (which has also been installed for quite a while). I uninstalled `ifupdown`, rebooted the computer, and then purged `ifupdown`. However, a file has been left over:

```
Löschen der Konfigurationsdateien von libssl1.1:i386 (1.1.1n-0+deb11u1) ...
Löschen der Konfigurationsdateien von ifupdown (0.8.41) ...
dpkg: Warnung: Während Entfernens von ifupdown ist Verzeichnis »/etc/network/interfaces.d« nicht leer, wird daher nicht gelöscht
```

which simply means that configuration files of `libssl1.1:i386` and `ifupdown` have been removed and `/etc/network/interfaces.d` is nonempty and has not been removed. Inside the directory, there's just one file

```
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 24  2021 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Jun 12 04:55 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   67 Jan 13  2021 setup
```

containing very little:

```
# cat setup 
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# auto eth0
# iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

However, when I try to understand to whom does this file belong to, I get no results:

```
# dpkg -S interfaces.d/setup
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *interfaces.d/setup*
# dpkg -S interfaces.d
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *interfaces.d*
```

Can I remove `/etc/interfaces.d/setup` or is it still good for anything? If I can remove the file `setup`, how about the directory `/etc/interfaces.d` ?